# Script to load controllers dynamically for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular.js, dom, promise, iteration

*I would like to hear your thoughts, idea's or feedback on the following code.*

**Ive added to code to github.**

https://github.com/redbullzuiper/angularjs-dynamic-controllers

---

Usually when you attach a controller to a DOM element using `ng-controller="myController"`, you need to include the controller somewhere in your page; for instance:

```
<script src="src/application/controllers/my-controller.js"></script>
```

However, when including the script I wrote in the `head`, it will traverse across the DOM and search for all `ng-controller` attributes.

It will then automatically append the correct controller into the `head` of the page. After it's done including all the controllers, it will manually bootstrap the application using:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['module_name']);
```

This way all controllers are getting loaded dynamically, without the need of including all controllers in your `head`. But they will instead only get loaded when called.

**[Can't create a demo using a fiddle, but a working demo can be found here](https://codepen.io/richardmauritz/project/editor/ZwapEa#)**

### **The code:**

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    var promises = [];
    var ngApp = document.querySelectorAll('[ng-app]')[0];
    var ngControllers = document.querySelectorAll('[ng-controller]');

    // Throw warning if angular is not found
    if(typeof angular == 'undefined')
    {
        console.warn("simplify error: Angular not found, operation canceled.");
        return;
    }

    // Throw warning if ng-app directive exists. Script will bootstrap the application manually
    if(ngApp)
    {
        console.warn("Please remove the ng-app directive. `Simplify` will bootstrap the application manually.");
        console.warn("This will also most likely fix the 'Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]' error.");
    }

    // Append the scripts
    for(var i = 0;i < ngControllers.length;i++)
    {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var src = 'src/application/controllers/'+ ngControllers[i].getAttribute('ng-controller') + '.controller.js';
            var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.setAttribute('src', src);

            document.head.appendChild(script);

            script.addEventListener('load', function() {
                resolve(script);
            });
        });

        // Push promises to array to resolve them all together later on
        promises.push(promise);
    }

    // Resolve all promises then bootstrap the app
    // Without the use of promises, the bootstrap will start before all scripts are included
    // This results into an erro
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {     
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Feedback

This is an interesting way of loading controllers. I like the application of the promises. It does feel a little weird not to have an `ng-app` directive but it makes sense given the nature of your code.

### Suggestions

The suggestions below can simplify the code, but may not necessarily be optimal or have desired browser support.

#### Iterating functionally

One could utilize a functional approach instead of the declarative `for` loop:

> ```
> for(var i = 0;i < ngControllers.length;i++)
> ```

Because each iteration pushes a promise into the array `promises`, that loop can be replaced by a call to `Array.map()`:

```
var promises = Array.prototype.map.call(ngControllers, function(ngController)
```

Or `.map` could be called on an array after converting the nodeList to an array via [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (but beware of [Browser compatibilty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility) on that)

```
var promises = Array.from(ngControllers).map(function(ngController)
```

Or for a completely es-6 approach, use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
var promises = [...ngControllers].map(function(ngController)
```

At the end of each iteration, simply return the promise instead of pushing it into the array.

```
    // Push promises to array to resolve them all together later on
    return promise;//promises.push(promise);
}); //end the call to .map()
```

Bear in mind that the functional approach would likely be somewhat slower because a function call is added for each iteration, but for a small number of controllers this should be a negligible difference. If you would like to become more familiar with functional JavaScript, I recommend [these exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/).

#### Use partial(-ly applied) functions for callbacks

Instead of making a closure just to call `resolve()`:

> ```
> script.addEventListener('load', function() {
>     resolve(script);
> });
> ```

Use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (different than ([`angular.bind()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind)) to create a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) for each time `resolve()` is called.

```
script.addEventListener('load', resolve.bind(null, script));
```

Bear in mind that the event listener would pass an `event` argument to the callback, but that should be the second argument when `script` is bound as the first argument.

The same is true for calling the bootstrap function after all promises have been resolved:

> ```
> Promise.all(promises).then(function() {       
>     angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
> });
> ```

Can be simplified like below:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(angular.bootstrap.bind(null, document, ['app']));
```

#### Use `addEventListener` instead of `onload`

This likely wouldn't be an issue in a small application but in case there was other code (potentially multiple functions) that needed to be executed when the page is loaded, it might be simpler just to use `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...})` instead of `window.onload = function() {...};`

Comment: I'm really happy with the suggestions. Especially the way you suggest to handle the `addEventListerner`. Thats indeed a much simpler approach. I will make these changes in the github project and codepen. I appreciate your time and effort!